# JavaScript file isn't being displayed onto webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was looking for help displaying a JavaScript file onto the front of my webpage. When connecting js file to html it doesn't display the file onto the webpage. looking into inspect it shows that the canvas is there as well as testing to see if the js file is connected through console shows that it is connected. I don't know how to fix this. here is the image that shows the canvas is on the webpage

[image]

here is the code:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

const numStars = 500;
let stars = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(2);

  for (let i = 0; i < numStars; i++) {
    stars.push(new Star(random(width), random(height)));
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 50);

  const acc = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0.005, 0.2);

  stars = stars.filter(star => {
    star.draw();
    star.update(acc);
    return star.isActive();
  });

  while (stars.length < numStars) {
    stars.push(new Star(random(width), random(height)));
  }
}

class Star {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.pos = createVector(x, y);
    this.prevPos = createVector(x, y);

    this.vel = createVector(0, 0);

    this.ang = atan2(y - (height / 2), x - (width / 2));
  }

  isActive() {
    return onScreen(this.prevPos.x, this.prevPos.y);
  }

  update(acc) {
    this.vel.x += cos(this.ang) * acc;
    this.vel.y += sin(this.ang) * acc;

    this.prevPos.x = this.pos.x;
    this.prevPos.y = this.pos.y;

    this.pos.x += this.vel.x;
    this.pos.y += this.vel.y;
  }

  draw() {
    const alpha = map(this.vel.mag(), 0, 3, 0, 255);
    stroke(255, alpha);
    line(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.prevPos.x, this.prevPos.y);
  }
}

function onScreen(x, y) {
  return x >= 0 && x <= width && y >= 0 && y <= height;
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DynaPuff:wght@600&family=Shadows+Into+Light&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "DynaPuff", cursive;
}

.canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}

body {
  min-height: 25%;
  background: linear-gradient(#868686, #000000);
}

.navbar-container {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar {
  max-width: 1560px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  color: #ffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

ul li a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

ul li a:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out
}

.jumping-letters {
  /* make the transformation smooth over 0.5 seconds */
  animation: jump 1s infinite;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  /* apply the jump animation */
}

@keyframes jump {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out/* move the letters up by 10 pixels */
  }
}

.hello {
  color: #ffff;
  display: grid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  flex: auto;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowarp;
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-size: 1em;
  z-index: 5;
}

.projects {
  position: relative;
  color: #000000;
}

.education {
  position: relative;
  color: #000000;
}

.aboutme {
  position: relative;
  color: #000000;
}

.resume {
  position: relative;
  color: #000000;
}

.body-container1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 75vw;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.body-container1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 75vw;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.body-container2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 75vw;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.body-container3 {
  background-color: #fff;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 75vw;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.body-container4 {
  background-color: #fff;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 75vw;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sec {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Mustafa Said</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />

</head>
<div>
<canvas class="canvas">
<script src="space.js"></script>
</canvas>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-container">
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul class="jumping-letters">
          <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#education">Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="#aboutme">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="hello">
        <div>
          <p class="jumping-letters2">Hello, I'm</p>
          <h1 class="jumping-letters2">Mustafa Said</h1>
          <h3 class="jumping-letters2">but most call me moosee</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section id="projects" class="sec projects">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="body-container1">
        <div class="column1">
          <h2>Projects</h2>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3>The Illumihat - Python</h3>
            <p>
            </p>
            <h3>Project Snowflake - JavaScript</h3>
            <p></p>
            <h3>Personal Portfolio - HTML, CSS</h3>
            you're looking right at it :)
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="education" class="sec education">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="body-container2">
        <div class="Education">
          <h2>Education</h2>
          <div class="desc">
            <h3>
              
            </h3>
            <p>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="aboutme" class="sec aboutme">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="body-container3">
        <div class="column1">
          <h2>About Me</h2>
          <div class="desc">
            <p>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="resume" class="sec resume">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="body-container4">
        <div class="column1">
          <h2>Resume</h2>
          <div class="desc">
            <p>
              
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer></footer>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: You're creating a `canvas` element in your JavaScript, but you're not adding it to the document anywhere. It will not magically replace the `canvas` element declared in your HTML. You'd have to do something like `document.body.appendChild(canvas)` to add the created element to your document. Also, your HTML is lacking a `body` element.

Comment: @ahmedmoeed It's sufficiently clear from the question what the author is trying to achieve. Your manufactured indignation has no place on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove personal information from the code that you posted, such as your name, location, university, and faculty.

That being said, your JavaScript is likely loading but there are a couple of issues that are causing it to not run.

Firstly, don't put the script inside the canvas tags. And remove the `#` prefixes from your HTML. The relevant lines in your HTML should look like:

```html
<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="space.js"></script>
```

Secondly, your JavaScript is creating a new canvas instead of loading the element that's already on your page. Use `querySelector` to find the `<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>` element on the page. The relevant lines in your JavaScript should look like

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Finally, your JavaScript code isn't actually running any of the functions that you've written. At the end of your code put:

```js
setup();
draw();
```

Comment: hello thank you for taking time to write. i tried out what u stated with the querySelector but it is still having the same issue with the js not being displayed. If you know of any other way please lmk :)

Comment: upon further investigation, it seems to have moved the canvas to the absolute bottom of the screen but there is still nothing being displayed on it :(

Comment: @moosee updated with a possible solution

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a few changes to make your website load your script and run it.

First of all, `canvas` tag cannot have `script` tag as a child:

```
<canvas class="canvas"/>
<script src="space.js"></script>
```

The second change is that you don't need to create a `canvas` tag because you have it in your `html` already. However, you need get reference to that `canvas` tag from your script:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
```

The third and actually most trickiest thing is that your script can start execution BEFORE your HTML page is fully loaded and parsed into DOM tree. Therefore, before trying to do `document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')` you need to make sure that the page is fully loaded.

To do this you need something like:

```
var canvas;
var c;
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
  c = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // now we have everything to start setup() and other functions
});
```

Let me know if this helps.